# Mounted Share Drive showed incorrect Last Opened Date at "Get Info" dialog

Tags: macos, mount, ntfs

I have a shared drive mounted via SMB. The "Get Info" page shows that the Last Opened time is January 1, 1970, which is obviously impossible.

What is the cause of the issue, and is it possible to fix this?

[image]

p.s. the Last modified date is also incorrect.

Comment: 1/1/70 is the Unix Epoch which means the timestamp stored for Last opened for this share is 0 or null. Given that it's an NTFS share, I would guess OS X is reading something incorrectly, or the share is reporting something incorrectly. Has this always shown up like this? What version of OS X?

Comment: OS X version : Yosemite OS X 10.10.2. The date is always shown up like this.